# Bursty data transfer with Dummynet

Tags: linux, networking, network-programming, freebsd

I'm trying to use Dummynet to test the behaviour of my network application in various network conditions. The emulator was compiled and installed on an Ubuntu 12.04 box. I'm experiencing a strange behaviour when I reduce the bandwidth of the link/path.

For some reason, instead of having a slow download speed. It seems as if the download is happening in bursts! A portion of the data is downloaded at a high speed, then the data transfer stops for a period of time and then resumes again (and so on). Does anyone have an idea what could be the cause? Or is this even expected?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already do that, but for ensure you must to do the follow:

Compile a new kernel with support for IPFW and Dummynet, putting this lines on your kernel config file:

```
options IPDIVERT
options IPFIREWALL
options IPFIREWALL_VERBOSE
options IPFIREWALL_FORWARD
options DUMMYNET
options HZ=1000
```

After that compile and install your new kernel. To do that follow the steps on [Building and Installing a Custom Kernel](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/kernelconfig-building.html)

Doing that, configure the rc.conf file with this lines:

```
firewall_enable="YES"
firewall_type="OPEN"
```

If you are not using the default firewall conf file `/etc/rc.firewall` then put your config file like this, instead "OPEN":

```
firewall_type="/your/firewall/config.file"
```

for testing purposes you can write yours rules directly on console an see what happens, and after write this on your config file to preserve the rules.

for a basic bandwith limit this rules must be enough:

```
ipfw pipe 1 config bw 1Mbit
ipfw pipe 2 config bw 1Mbit
```

Now you have two pipes with 1Mbit of bandwidth each, lets put the traffic on this pipes.

```
ipfw add pipe 1 tcp from any to me
ipfw add pipe 2 tcp from me to any
```

Doing this your is limiting your self to pipes previously created.

This is basic for Dummynet bandwidth control.